# What is the purpose of the ROI layer in a Fast R-CNN?

Tags: deep-learning, computer-vision, conv-neural-network, object-detection

In [this](https://leonardoaraujosantos.gitbooks.io/artificial-inteligence/content/object_localization_and_detection.html) tutorial about object detection, the fast R-CNN is mentioned. The ROI (region of interest) layer is also mentioned.

What is happening, mathematically, when region proposals get resized according to final convolution layer activation functions (in each cell)?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

***Region-of-Interest(RoI) Pooling:***

It is a type of pooling layer which performs *max pooling* on inputs (here, convnet feature maps) of non-uniform sizes and produces a small feature map of fixed size (say 7x7). The choice of this fixed size is a network hyper-parameter and is predefined.

The main purpose of doing such a pooling is to speed up the training and test time and also to train the whole system from end-to-end (in a joint manner).

It's because of the usage of this pooling layer the training & test time is faster compared to original(vanilla?) R-CNN architecture and hence the name *Fast R-CNN.*

Simple example (from [Region of interest pooling explained by deepsense.io](https://deepsense.io/region-of-interest-pooling-explained/)):

[image: Visualization of RoI Pooling]

Comment: Here the region proposals means just the shape of the region in the image or portion of image with pixels then get multiplied with max filter values ?

Comment: @ShamaneSiriwardhana Region proposal means A Method to propose Region of Interest from the image.

Answer (score 18):

ROI (region of interest) layer is introduced in [Fast R-CNN](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1504.08083.pdf) and is a special case of spatial pyramid pooling layer which is introduced in [Spatial Pyramid Pooling in Deep Convolutional
Networks for Visual Recognition](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1406.4729.pdf). The main function of ROI layer is reshape inputs with arbitrary size into a fixed length output because of size constraint in Fully Connected layers.

How ROI layer works is showed below:

[image]

In this image, the input image with arbitrary size is fed into this layer which has 3 different window: 4x4 (blue), 2x2 (green), 1x1 (gray) to produce outputs with fixed size of 16 x F, 4 x F, and 1 x F, respectively, where F is the number of filters. Then, those outputs are concatenated into a vector to be fed to Fully Connected layer.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the point "because of size constraint in Fully Connected layers". Since we are feeding pixel values (scalars) into the neurons of the FC layer, why does it matter what is the size of the input matrix.

Comment: "size constraint" refers to dimension of input image. For example, LeNet-5 can only take 32x32 images so you can feed 64x64 or 64x32 images into it without resizing, which will eventually cause loss in the transformation. This constraint is due to the first fully connected layer "need to have fixed size/length input by their definition".

Comment: The size constraint of FC layers is because an FC layer performs the same operation as matrix-vector multiplication.  The matrix contains the parameters and is a fixed size, so hence the input vector must be the matching size.

Comment: RPN predicts the bbox coordinates. How is this prediction mapped to a conv layer from which the RoIPooling is extracted? Obviously conv layer's parameters H and W are small, unlike predicted bbox

Comment: Also, convlayers typically have many maps (e.g. 512). Are they all used for RoI pooling?